# Unsupported class file major version 61 error

Tags: flutter

I am trying to run a flutter app, and this error appeared while trying to, what I did was that I wanted to run flutter apps without android studio, so I download android SDK and JDK 17, after I ran flutter doctor and it gave me that everything is good, I tried to run and it gave me this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\Flutter Apps\first_app\android\build.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'E:\Flutter Apps\first_app\android\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 61
.............
```

So I tried an older version of JDK, it gave me another error, so I saw a third solution to run with JDK 17, which is to downgrade the gradle in gradle.properties, but it just gave me a fourth error, so does anyone know a final solution for this error ??

Comment: Your java and/or javac at level 1.17 are not activated. Somehow it's picking up an earlier version. Check PATH. You can do this at a command line with `javac -version`

Comment: I really think that it has something between the compatability of JDK version and gradle

Comment: @g00se it printed javac 17

Comment: I think that this is the problem [compatability](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html)

Comment: a. make sure that version is the one being used by your IDE. Also the same with `java`

Comment: so I downloaded JDK 16 and updated gradle to 7.0 -according to the compatablity table, so it ran at first but then gave me this error

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @ac71d33

Comment: @DeveloperOmar100 I am facing the same problem did you find the solution?

Answer (score 29):

Based on the answer of DeveloperOmar 100 I found the following solution:

1. switch your Java version to a [compatible version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html), in my case to Java [version 16.0.2](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk16-archive-downloads.html)

   To switch it you have to set your PATH. (e.g for Mac, you can use the [`java_home`](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/#switch-between-different-jdk-versions) command).
2. check your Gradle version and update that one too, so it is compatible (see the [Gradle wrapper docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)) so in my case I had to change the `distributionUrl` property in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`:

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
   ```

Comment: Using the gradle distribution distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip worked for me with Java 16.0.2 as of Dec 2021

Comment: Note that as of version 7.3, Gradle supports Java 17, so setting the `distributionUrl` version to the latest 7.3.x (e.g. 7.3.3 at this writing) should take care of the problem.

Comment: I found that I had to switch back to a compatible version of Java before I could follow the Gradle upgrade procedure at https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html. Also, my GRADLE_HOME environment variable may have been part of my problem.

Comment: Same error, I'm on MacOs, and JDK is: openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18

Answer (score 8):

For me, upgrading Gradle fixed the issue. I just had to do change this line in the *gradle-wrapper.properties* file:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

Comment: This solution works for me. I have updated my Gradle from 6.7 to 7.4.

Answer (score 4):

**SOLUTION**

**1, Edit gradle path: 6.7 => 7.3**

[image]

**2, Update classpath: 4.1.0 => 7.0.0**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and after trying all the jdk based solutions, it turned out that my installed Gradle was outdated - 7.0.2 was installed, which doesn't support JDK 17.

You can check your Gradle version with: gradle -version

Check which Gradle you need for a specific version of Java here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

After updating it to the latest version the issue went away:
https://gradle.org/install/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when I tried out Kotlin/Compose on my windows computer. I followed the instructions at https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Getting_Started

I struggled with this for a few hours before I finally was able to solve all the problems I encountered.

### Solution

- In gradle settings changed Gradle JVM: 11 (version 11.0.12)
- In build.gradle.kts I deleted

  tasks.withType {
  kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "16"
  }

### What caused the problems

I started by installing

- latest JDK (version 17)
- IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2 (Community Edition)

Then I created a 'hello world' example with following settings:

- Project template: Compose Desktop Application uses Kotlin 1.5.31
- Build system: Gradle Kotlin
- Project JDK: 17 Oracle OpenJDK version 17.0.2
- Template: Compose Desktop Module
- Target JVM version: 16
- Test framework: JUnit 5

When the project was created I updated build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
  id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.0.1"
}
```

### First error at build

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 61

I fixed this by changing gradle settings

- Gradle JVM: 11 (version 11.0.12)

Now the build was ok but run would fail

### Second error at run

> Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

This was solved by deleting

```
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
  kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "16"
}
```

in build.gradle.kts

Answer (score 0):

I have java 17 and tried to execute Junit version 4 and this is where I faced this exact error.

However I have downgraded my java version to 11, re-ran the code and viola, this error is gone.

Alternatively I could have upgraded the Junit version to 5 without disturbing the java version 17, choice is yours as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when using WSL (Ubuntu), I had java 11 installed, but for classfile 61 to work I needed to install Java 17 which fixed it

1. **Update Your Package List**

   ```bash
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. **Install OpenJDK 17**

   ```bash
   sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk -y
   ```
3. **Verify Installation**:

   ```bash
   java -version
   ```

Answer (score -8):

Simply remove java 17 from the system. Thats helped me

Comment: Based on how this answer is written, it's unclear that removing Java17 is the root cause of the problem or simply just a good idea.

Comment: only removing java17 helped me

Comment: OK. May I suggest that you edit your answer to: Simply remove Java17 from the system.

Comment: Adding the "helps" makes it sound like an "aid" rather than a solution. But your meaning is that it is a solution. :-)

Comment: Ok, tnx, im not a native speaker

Comment: No problem Anuar. Keep contributing! I'm not a native speaker in other languages and I still post on social media there. So keep at it.

Comment: remove if you have more than one jdk version on your device