# BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61 in intellija idea

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, build-script, semantic-analysis

BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 61

[image]

Comment: Which version of Gradle are you using? And which version of the JDK?

Answer (score 2):

I got this yesterday too. Check the version of Gradle you are using vs the version of the JDK.

Since you're not using the Gradle wrapper, maybe for you it's just a matter of upgrading Gradle and/or the JDK.

I was using the Gradle wrapper so it's a bit different, but essentially the problem was that I updated my wrapper properties to Gradle 7.3.3, but the currently downloaded gradle was still the old one (too old) which was not compatible with my JDK 17.

For some reason, I needed to configure Gradle in IDEA to use the properties file instead of the wrapper task for it to work:

[image: gradle settings menu dropdown]

[image: gradle settings wrapper properties]

Comment: I got this problem when I wanted to try Kotlin/Compose on my windows computer. I followed https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Getting_Started and installed latest version of jdk and IntelliJ IDEA.
When I tried to set use 'grade-wrapper.properties' I got error that the file doesn't exist. Instead I had to set Gradle JVM to version 11.0.12 which was already installed.

Comment: Hm, I still can't get it to work. After changes done in my previous comment I can build. But when I try to run I get this error: "> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1"

IntelliJ/Gradle/Kotlin/Compose/What-ever seems to be a real mess...

Comment: I was finally able to solve the problems, see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69425829/unsupported-class-file-major-version-61-error/71276762#71276762