# Package Build gradle failed

Tags: flutter, dart

everytime i add google_maps_flutter package i always get this error but in another project it's fine.

Please help...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.1.2\android\build.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.1.2\android\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 61

  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
```

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69425829/unsupported-class-file-major-version-61-error solution?

Comment: i just fix it a few second ago by that post lol