# Flutter without Android Studio RUNning on vscode Error Flutter doctor all's good But run terminal error

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

[no error on flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjsGy.jpg)

[But vscode terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvx3c.jpg)

Comment: Check This : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69425829/unsupported-class-file-major-version-61-error

Answer (score 0):

[E:\Web_Designing\Study_v3.2\flutter\demo\flutter_application_1\android\build.gradle and change classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCmeK.jpg)

Comment: go to flutter\demo\flutter_application_1\android\build.gradle and change classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Flutter on vscode without android studio

1. all flutter doctor (✔) [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfHno.jpg)
2. and install java sdk 17+
3. gradle latest version install (ex.distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.1-all.zip)
4. and gradle latest version plugin (https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)
   change classpath 7.1.1 (go to your (flutter_project_folder)\android\build.gradle and change classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'
5. finally try to run