# How to make a JDK 17 library works on JDK 11 project (Unsupported class file major version 61)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm getting build errors when I include a JDK 17 library(aar) in my android project.

`Android Studio: Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1` 
`AGP: 4.1.2`
`Gradle: 6.5`
`Gradle JDK: 11.0.20.1`
`Kotlin: 1.3.72`
`minSdkVersion: 28`
`targetSdkVersion: 33`

I tried to update my Gradle JDK to `17.0.7` but get the same error.

I also tried solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69425829/unsupported-class-file-major-version-61-error), but still getting version 61 error:

Note: I am using [Butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) library on my other modules which doesn't support JDK 17